# Where can I find monster hair?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I have been looking for monster hair in The Witcher 3 for hours and I can't find it. Can you buy it or what monsters do I kill to find it?

Comment: I got some from destroying monster nests.

Comment: Dismantle some of the monster stuff you have, is the general idea I see on the interwebs.

Answer (score 9):

> Monster hair can be obtained by dismantling several items you loot from monsters, including **Fiend’s Eye**, **Nightwraith Hair**, **Chort Hide**, **Werewolf Hide** and **Troll Hide**.

[Here's](http://www.gosunoob.com/witcher-3/monster-hair/) a guide about Monster Hair.

Basically Werewolf Hide is a good choice because you come across one in a Side-Quest.

[**Spoiler Alert**]

> It's the **Wild at Heart Quest**

There's also the Fiend that you come across one in a Side-Quest aswell

[**Spoiler Alert**]

> The **Return to CrookBak Bog Quest**

In [this guide](http://www.gosunoob.com/witcher-3/lesser-red-mutagen-farming-location/) it also gives some good locations to farming Fiends.

Last but not least the Guide states that Skelliges Caverns hold some Trolls for you to farm.

Follow these steps and you'll have plenty monster hair. If you don't know how to dismantle just go to a **Blacksmith** or **Armorer** and go to the **Dismantle** option.

Usually there is the **Shop**, **Crafting**, **Repair**, **Upgrade** and **Dismantle** Options.

Hope I Helped

Comment: @wicher3123 please consider accepting the answer since it helped you

Answer (score -2):

Skelliga flying sirens usually found on sea coasts are the best. After obtaining the hairs turn them into monster hair using blacksmith dismantling panel .
I farmed for five hours no monster dropped it . Shops alchemist and herbalist had nothing 
What I mentioned above helped me best

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer dismantling other things is the easiest way to get monster hair.